# How do I route Zend properly when there are multiple subdomain sections?

Tags: zend-framework, routes, subdomain, wildcard

I set up a wildcard domain for my website, which works fine with all kind of words and characters, but fails when there is an extra dot in the subdomain. The path should point to my data page where I can get the subdomain as a `param`, but instead it points back to my index page when there is a '.' in the subdomain.

For example, a valid url would be `http://peter.pan.example.com` (works; goes to data page), but could also be `http://peter.von.pan.example.com` (fails; goes to index page).

What needs to be changed in the current routing to make the second url route as desired?

Relevant Code:

```
resources.router.routes.subdomain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.route = ":module.example.com"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.defaults.reqs.module = "(.+)"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.defaults.controller = "data"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```